# how can i find the no.of files with a list of target extensions eg:.txt, .pdf etc and print it separately for current and sub directories using python

Tags: python, file

```
import  os

def fileCount(folder):
    "count the number of files in a directory"

    count = 0

    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        path = os.path.join(folder, filename)

        if os.path.isfile(path):
            count += 1
        elif os.path.isdir(path):
            count += fileCount(path)
    print(folder,'having',count)
    return count
fileCount('.')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import glob

def countMe(MyPath,typeofFile):
    numInstances = len(glob.glob1(MyPath,'*.'+typeofFile))
    return numInstances
```

`typeofFile` should be a string of the extension you are looking for. If you are looking for `.pdf` then `typeofFile = 'pdf'`

Comment: am having a list of types like pdf txt like and it should recursively compare in subdirectories also and want to print no of every type into a file for each directory seperately

Comment: Can you give an example of your expected input and output?

Comment: expected input will be like list[pdf,txt,jpeg] and a directory structure consits of subdirectories and files of different types. and output should be like a table  foldername    no.of.pdf  no of.txt   no of.jpeg   in a csv format